# Gitlab auto DevOps pipeline with docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, devops, gitlab-autodevops

I have a GitLab instance with build and deployment on a remote server.
Everything is working as expected but I'm wondering if it is possible to use docker with GitLab's Auto DevOps?
In [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/) only mention is about [Kubernetes-based](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/autodevops/#deploy-your-app-to-a-cloud-provider) solutions.
I could do this on Minikube, but before that, I want to exclude the possibility with achieving the same on Bear docker.

Thanks for any advice :)

Answer (score 0):

The [Auto DevOps feature](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/autodevops/requirements.html) supports Kubernetes or Amazon ECS and EC2.